# I don't understand the syntax error in my code

Tags: javascript

my text editor does not like this piece of code I am not sure why

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function randmg(){
var img = [
      "banner1.png",
      "banner2.png",
      "banner3.png",
      "banner4.png"
]
var maxImg = img.length;
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxImg)
return img[randNum]
}
</script>
```

It says the error is in line four "var img - ["

I thought that i was the use/placement of var under the array but I have not been able to fix it

Changed to this

```
function randmg(){
var img = ["banner1.png","banner2.png","banner3.png","banner4.png"];
var maxImg = img.length;
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxImg);
return img[randNum];
}
```

But still having the same issue

Comment: OK this is weird I just created a new .js file and I wrote a new function for something else an I have the same error on the first line under the function definition. Now I am really lost. Will syntax errors cause the rest of your code not to execute?

Comment: Everything seems alright (the second one), you should tell us the exact error display and sometimes this kind of errors are from stuff before this, like `{` no closed or alike. Yeah why would you want to do everything with Closures? They in the advanced level and most ppl that use them just doesn't do it correctly and end up wasting memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you need to add a semicolen at the end of that array.

```
var img = [
      "banner1.png",
      "banner2.png",
      "banner3.png",
      "banner4.png"
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have semicolons and the end of each statement:

```
 function randmg(){
      var img = [
            "banner1.png",
            "banner2.png",
            "banner3.png",
            "banner4.png"
      ]; //here
      var maxImg = img.length;
      var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxImg); //here
      return img[randNum]; //here
 }
```

Although they aren't **required** due to legacy reasons, they are strongly encouraged.  In this case the code runs, but that is no reason to omit them.

Comment: I fixed my mistakes but I am still having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Consider this rewrite:

```
var randmg = (function () {
    var img = [
        'banner1.png',
        'banner2.png',
        'banner3.png',
        'banner4.png'
    ];

    return function () {
        return img[ Math.floor( Math.random() * img.length ) ];
    };
})();
```

Comment: Why return a function from randmg?  What's wrong with just having a function named randmg() like originally done?

Comment: @jfriend00 In OP's original code the `img` array is evaluated each time the function is invoked. Those repeated evaluations are not necessary. We can evaluate the array only once (inside the immediately invoked function) and than make that array accessible to the function via closure. Beside this performance improvement, I believe that my code also reads better - unlike OP's code, here it's easy to distinguish that the array is a static resource and that the function uses this resource.

Comment: OK, I get your point about the evaluation of the img array, but I disagree that your code is easier to read or understand.  A JS newbie would not find your code near as easy to understand.  Yours is a more advanced implementation with one advantage, but simplicity is not one of those advantages.

Comment: I agree with jfriend00 as I am a newbie and do not understand. nor have i gotten the error to go away.

Comment: I got it finally how stupid, I am sure if I was more specific you would of got this. This is in a external file and you cannot have script tags in a external file!

Comment: @EdwardNickAJubrey Funny mistake `:)`